# ROA type of composite variable as dependent variable and total assets as IV

Tags: regression

Im struggling to form a regression model as i have to explain financial performance of a company. The problem is that I have a variable like Return on assets (ebit/total assets) as a dependent variable and id like to control for total assets. How can I perform the analysis? I guess the coefficient of independent variable is neither consistent nore unbiased in this situation. Can I instead run a regression using only "ebit" as a dependent variable and "total assets" as independent variable so there wouldnt be "total assets" in the dependent variable anymore.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd rather see log of the numerator as $Y$ and log of the denominator as one of the $X$s.  But see http://www.citeulike.org/user/harrelfe/article/13264437 .

This should have been posted to stats.stackexchange.com